# Identity login without a password

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, passwords, asp.net-identity

I have this test account that is saved in AspNetUsers *(with password)*, AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles. What I want is to login this account using only the UserName *(without a password)*.

I tried using the `SignInManager.SignInAsync()` but I failed when it redirects to a page with Authorize attribute, it seems that it does not authenticate the user.

```
public ActionResult Confirmation(string userName)
{
    var user = UserManager.FindByName(userName);
    SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, true, true);
    return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");
}
[Authorize(Roles = "Member")]
public ActionResult Action()
{
    // do something
}
```

How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I found that these two links can solve this problem.

- [Authentication Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126344/authenticate-a-user-in-asp-net-mvc-5-without-password)
- [Role Based Claims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410748/asp-net-identity-role-based-claims)